# Xamarin. How can i perform validation to Entry value inside ListView on Button click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with multiple entries. In each, i should enter a value which would be compared to another value (the value is valid if higher or equal).
I must implement a solution that can check if all entries in ListView are valid when i tap a submit button.

I implemented a kind of validation using behaviors but it just highlights the entry value when it's not valid and it doesn't affect the button.

```html
<ListView x:Name="lstRegistadores" ItemsSource="{Binding Contador.Registadores}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Entry x:Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Corrente.Valor}"  >
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <local:RegistadorValidatorBehavior  />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>                                                  
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Text="Confirmar" />
```

```c
public class RegistadorValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(RegistadorValidatorBehavior), false);

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
            private set { base.SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var entry = sender as Entry;
            var registador = (Registador)entry.BindingContext;
            var compareTo = registador.Ultimo.Valor;

            int valor;


            IsValid = (int.TryParse(e.NewTextValue,out valor) && valor >= compareTo) ;

            entry.TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone show me the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to check [FluentValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/6.4.0-beta9) and apply it to *Contador.Registadores*.

FluentValidation is one of those essentials libraries that works very well with Xamarin.

This article should give you insights how FluetValidation can help you to check you entire list and complex subproperties:

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/b.-Creating-a-Validator